# Positive solution of Diophantine linear equation

Tags: number-theory

$ \underline {Positive \ \  solution  \ \ of  \ \ Diophantine \ \  linear  \ \ equation : } \ $

Consider the Diophantine equation

$$ px+qy=n \ $$

where $ \ p , \ q \ $ are positive integers and $ \ n \ $ is non-negative integers.

$ \ (a) \ $ Prove that if $ \ gcd(p,q) $ is a factor of $ \ n \ $ , then

(i) If $ \ n>pq-p-q \ $ , there is at least one solution in positive integers $ \ x \ \ and \ \ y \ $ .

(ii) If $ \ n=pq-p-q \ $  , there is no solution in positive integers .

**Answer:**

$ \ (i) \ $

Let $ \ d=gcd(p,q) \ $  and given that $ \ d \ | \ n \ $.

Now $ \ d \ | n \Rightarrow n=kd \ $ , for some $ \ k \in \mathbb{Z} \ $

Now since $ \ n \ $  is  non-negative integer , $ \ k \ $ is also non-negative.

Since $ \ p , q \ $ are positive integers ,  $ \ gcd(p,q)=d \geq 1 \ $

**But now I can not prove the the conclusion of (i)**

please get through the solution at least first one.

Comment: `\text{}` allows you to write text inside equations. Putting `=`'s under a line turns it into a title line.

Comment: You're only using definitions, you need to start with what you have to prove and say " Let $n>pq-p-q$...[argumentation]...then we have that there is atleast one solution in $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$

Comment: If $\text{gcd}(p,q)>n$, then it is not a factor of $n$. Positive integers do not have factors that are greater than themselves.

Comment: I made correction of my question

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you.